# Subclassing my custom cell class with another?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoapods

https://cocoapods.org/pods/BWSwipeRevealCell

I'm looking to use this pod in my project. It lets users swipe on a cell and run a function once the cell has been swiped far enough.

In every pod I see that's like this on cocoapods, the instructions are to cast your cell as their class like

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! BWSwipeRevealCell
```

I've got a custom cell class that has all of my necessary functions and labels. I was thinking I could do something like

```
class MainPageCell: BWSwipeCell {}
```

but I get "undeclared type of BWSWipeCell".

if I cmd + click onto the BWSwipeCell, it takes me to an open class of

```
BWSwipeCell:UITableViewCell {}
```

which has all of the code to make the cells work, so I'm not sure why I can't just subclass it.

Is there a graceful way to mash together my custom class's code and this pod's?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate import at the top of your file?

Comment: Whoops. That was it. Thanks man.

Comment: btw: how you create the cell (which code)?